# Or operator inside When function Spark Java API

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop

How to use Or operation inside when function in Spark Java API. I want something like this but I get a compiler error.

```
Dataset<Row> ds = ds1.withColumn("Amount2", when(ds2.col("Type").equalTo("A") Or ds2.col("Type").equalTo("B"), "Amount1").otherwise(0))
```

Can somebody guide me please with a sample expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `or` method:

```
ds2.col("Type").equalTo("A").or(ds2.col("Type").equalTo("B"))
```

With `equalTo` `isin` should work as well:

```
ds2.col("Type").isin("A", "B")
```